# How to load PHP file without using .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using this code to load the PHP  file without using php extension. It works good with localhost, but it gives error in live server.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.PHP [NC,L]
```

I have also used this solution, but it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: And _what_ error do you get? Sorry, but we cannot somehow magically _guess_ that.

Comment: @arkascha when i use this code i write it at the bottom but when i write at the top it works fine

Answer (score -1):

Always write the code at top of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What kind of advise is that? "Always at the top"... That certainly depends on the situation, on the order you want the rules to get applied.

Comment: Apart from that... this is _exactly_ the second attempt the OP showed in the question along with the note that it does not work...